# Custom content query web part field not displaying

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

Hello and thank you in advance. I have added a custom field to my CQWP by the standard process of copying an existing xsl template in ItemStyle.xsl and then adding the additional field. The field displays in the web part properties, but in a weird format and the  unfortunately the data does not display.   Please see code and screenshot for example. You can see a weird "$resource" error or something like that?

```
        <td width="120px">
        <div class="description">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@DatePublished),1033,'MMM d, yyyy')" />
          </div>
    </td>
    <!--Adam Add Amended Field-->
        <td width="120px">
        <div class="description_Amend">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Amended_x0020_Date),1033,'MMM d, yyyy')" />
          </div>
    </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The field names in ItemStyle.xsl are a little different. If we miss **_x005f** in the field name, it will break. Make sure to include the correct field names.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you baker, this worked. For the sake of consistency, I re-created the names without a space. Then, after creation i added the space which does not update the internal field name.  Thanks again!